# configuring thunderbird to run a given executable on each email recieved as an alias

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird

On my Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64 desktop `ours.starynkevitch.net` my favorite graphical MUA is [thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net) version 68.2

I don't want to install an MTA locally then use [procmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail). My thunderbird is configured for my `basile@starynkevitch.net` account, IMAP & SMTP [served by Gandi](https://www.gandi.net/en/domain/email).

But I would like every email sent to `team@refpersys.org` to be processed by some program or script `$HOME/bin/handle-refpersys-email` (à la `procmail`) started by my `thunderbird` process.

BTW, on [refpersys.org](http://refpersys.org/) the `team@` email address is a mailing alias to a few persons, including me.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: it is a bad idea to post a real email address

Comment: Mine is online since decades

Comment: I've never seen anything like that done. However, Thunderbird does have very powerful message filters that can do a lot of things for you like sorting mail into folders, adding tags, marking as read or even deleting. There are 18 actions available, but none of them involve running an external program. If you store copies of the messages locally (I have IMAP and I do that), the files are stored in mbox format, so any program that can process that common format should be able to process them as long as you don't break the indexes, etc.